# How to extract from jsonb array postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

One of my columns contains the below array. I just need the order_lookup_code. How do I do this?

| vendor_provided_data |
| --- |
| {"vendor_data": [{"order_id": 10000, "shipment_id": 20000, "order_lookup_code": "fr_30000dd"}]} |

Comment: If the array contains multiple elements, do you want multiple rows in the result?

Comment: No. Preferably just another column next to it showing just the order_lookup_code

Comment: Do you have an upper limit of the number of elements? You can't have dynamic columns in a SQL query. So you need to write a query with a pre-defined number of columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want multiple columns, you need one expression per column, e.g.

```
select vendor_provided_data #>> '{vendor_data, 0, order_lookup_code}' as code_1,
       vendor_provided_data #>> '{vendor_data, 1, order_lookup_code}' as code_2,
       vendor_provided_data #>> '{vendor_data, 2, order_lookup_code}' as code_3,
       ...
from the_table
```

The `#>>` operator extracts a "nested" element from a JSON value, along a "path" where each element of the array specifies a step in the path. The same could be achieved using multiple `->` operators. `{vendor_data, 0, 'order_lookup_code'}` is equivalent to `-> 'vendor_data' -> 0 -> 'order_lookup_code'`

If multiple rows are OK, you can use `jsonb_array_elements()`

```
select t.id, --<< whatever columns you want from the table
       vd.item ->> 'order_lookup_code' as lookup_code
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.vendor_provided_data -> 'vendor_data') as vd(item)
```

If you are on Postgres 12 or later, you could extract all codes as a single JSON array:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(vendor_provided_data, '$.vendor_data[*].order_lookup_code') as all_codes
from the_table
```

Comment: `select vendor_provided_data #>> '{vendor_data, 0, "order_lookup_code"}' as code_1`

Comment: This works! I just have to use a double quotation mark for order_lookup_code. Postgres was giving me a syntax error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the vendor_provided_data is your jsonb column .
This query would return you all records of table shipment with selection of order_lookup_code .

```
select jsonb_array_elements(vendor_provided_data->'vendor_data')->>'order_lookup_code' order_lookup_code
from shipment 
where 1 = 1
```